# How to show an application-modal "New Document" window on File > New / Cmd+N?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

Is there a recommended/common way for showing an application-modal "New Document" window when the user chooses File > New or presses Cmd+N?

I am talking about a window where the user can set initial document properties like page dimensions. There should be both OK and Cancel buttons, which means that dismissing the New Document window will not necessarily lead to an actual document window being created.

By the way, my application is `NSDocument`-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is fairly straightforward. Create a window and window controller for the new-document dialog. Have your app delegate instantiate them on startup or on demand. Set Cmd-N as the key equivalent for your File > New item, and connect it to an action in your app delegate which sets up and runs a modal session for that window (`[NSApp runModalForWindow:wc.window]`).

The window controller should end or cancel the modal session, decide whether or not to create the document (probably using `[-NSDocumentController openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:]`), and set the attributes you need to set.

That said, I urge you not to make it application-modal. Open a new document window and present a document-modal sheet which asks for and sets those dimensions instead. No reason to stop the user from doing whatever else s/he might be doing in  order to answer those questions.

Comment: Well, making a document-modal sheet was my first idea also. I tried it, but I failed to get it to work. I would always end up with the sheet appearing detached from the document window. I couldn't find something like `windowDidAppear:` where I could hook into for creating the sheet.

Comment: As for creating the application-modal window: You're right. What I'm asking should be rather straightforward to accomplish. However, I feel I don't completely understand how the Cocoa document architecture works yet. I already worked through Hillegass' book, but coverage is fairly cursory in there. (Which is understandable, as they had to find a way to make it fit into the book.) Do you have any recommendation where the Cocoa document architecture is explained clearly and more extensively?

Comment: I've mostly studied Cocoa's Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac. I'm sure it would be helpful to understand the architecture more deeply, though you don't need much of it for this particular task. The NSDocumentController method should be enough to get you started. Regarding the document-modal design, I handled this is in `-windowDidBecomeKey:`, using a newDocument variable in my NSDocument subclass which I set in `-initWithType:error:` (only invoked for new documents), and setting a hasBecomeKey instance variable to avoid presenting the panel more than once.

Comment: I would do a variation of this, where the window controller is instantiated in the MainMenu nib, but with “Visible on Launch” turned off, and the New command wired up to the WC's `showWindow:` action.

Comment: Sounds like an easier way to handle it.

Comment: I finally ended up with a window instead of a sheet, but I made it non-modal. That's basically the way Apple does it with the latest versions of their iWork applications. @noa: Your explanations were very helpful for doing this, thanks!